# How does InjectRepository work internally in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm

In nestjs, I understand that

```
imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TaskRepository]),
],
```

creates some kind of provider token so then I can inject the repository in my service (in same module) with this token.

What I don't understand is how `@InjectRepository()` works internally, for example:

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(TaskRepository)
    private taskRepository: TaskRepository,
  ) {}
```

How is `InjectRepository` custom decorator (which should have been created with `createParamDecorator`) able to inject a provider registered in a module? I researched and found out that `createParamDecorator` doesn't have ability to use DI. If `createParamDecorator` just creates a new `TaskRepository` instance and returns it, then why do I need to import `TypeOrmModule.forFeature` in module? Can someone explain how this works internally? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're on the right track, but `@InjectRespoitory()` and `createParamDecorator()` are generally two different decorator types. Yes they both work on parameters, but they generally have different use cases.

`createParamDecorator` works on controller, resolver, and gateway route handlers, so that Nest can know what part of the `req`, `context`, or `payload` object (or whatever other part of the `ExecutionContext` you want to get) should be put into the route handler's parameter position. The code behind that is a little complex, but I can point you to it if you get really curious.

`@InjectRepository()` on the other hand is an extension of `@Inject()` that takes the currently passed entity/repository and uses some logic to create a new injection token. Generally, this logic is `<EntityName>Repository` sometimes with a `connection` added to it. This token matches up with the created token from `TypeormModule.forFeature()` for the same entity. (Side note: if the entity passed is a repository, the token is just `<EntityName>` with the optional connection if it is not the default one).

You can try this out but getting rid of `@InjectRepository()` and instead using `@Inject()` just for testing purposes, but I wouldn't suggest that in a production server instance. Too many chances it will go wrong.

The really important thing to make note of here is that `@InjectRepository()` doesn't actually inject anything. It just sets up the metadata for Nest to read and match to a custom provider. `TypeormModule.forFeature()` is actually what's doing the heavy lifting here, creating a custom provider with a matching injection token and providing the right value for the provider.

By the way, `@InjectRepository()` and `TypeormModule.forFeature()` have to work together because Typescript cannot reflect generics properly. Normally with Nest we can use class names as injection tokens, but something like `Repository<TaskEntity>` just comes back as `Repository` so Nest wouldn't know *which* repository to inject. By using the `@InjectRepository()` decorator we are able to set the injection token metadata and override the reflected class value.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation!

Actually I found the file on github: https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/0cb781a605cf02812f792acd248320e6fd8449a0/lib/common/typeorm.decorators.ts

and kind of understood how it works but your explanation made everything much clearer